# Unexpected token export with TypeScript project - issue with transformIgnorePattern

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I have a TypeScript project with Jest testing that's working just fine, using ts-jest as my transformer. However when I try to use a package that appears to have been written in TypeScript, but was distributed as ES6, I'm running into the dreaded: "Unexpected token export" error when my tests run when it hits the "export" keyword on that new package.

I understand WHY it's happening, but I can't figure out how to get around it even after researching the issue extensively and seeing how others have fixed it with `transformIgnorePatterns` (like this post [comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2550#issuecomment-381718006) & so many others), but so far I've made no progress on it.

Tests run fine, until I import and reference one of these problem libraries. Simply adding:

```
import { Environment, EnvironmentType } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
...
const x: EnvironmentType = Environment.type;
```

...and then running my tests give me:

```
/Users/ac/_play/jest-transform-repro/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/index.js:11
export { default as _BrowserDetection } from './BrowserDetection';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I've created a project to easily repo my issue here: https://github.com/andrewconnell/jest-transform-repro

1. clone https://github.com/andrewconnell/jest-transform-repro
2. npm install
3. npm test

observe everything works

1. open file **./src/webparts/helloWorld/components/Sample/Sample.tsx** & uncomment the two lines
2. npm test

observe fail

I've tried updating my `transformIgnorePatterns` to `<rootDir>/../node_modules/(?!(@microsoft/sp-core-library))` and different flavors of this, but that's not helping. I've seen the posts about changing .bablerc => babel.config.js, but I'm not using Babel in my project as it's all TypeScript.

Once I get this working for this one library, I know I'll need to exclude more... a LOT more... so ideally I'd like to create something that addresses "@microsoft/*" packages and not just the one listed above as you can see from the default "npm install" in the repo above, there are a lot more that will give me issues.

Ideas? I'm at a loss :(

Answer (score 1):

These are the changes I did to get jest to work under a TS SPFX project:

`tsconfig.json`

- enable `"allowJs": true,`

`package.json`(add jest config):

```
    "jest": {    
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "json"
    ],

    "testURL": "http://localhost",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!(@microsoft/sp-dialog|@microsoft/office-ui-fabric-react-bundle|@microsoft/sp-diagnostics|@microsoft/sp-core-library|@microsoft/sp-http|@microsoft/sp-page-context|@microsoft/sp-dynamic-data|@pnp/sp|@pnp/common|@pnp/odata|@pnp))"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "**/src/**/*.test.+(ts|tsx|js)",
      "**/__tests__/**/*.(spec|test).+(tsx|ts|js)?(x)"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
      "^resx-strings/en-us.json": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@microsoft/sp-core-library/lib/resx-strings/en-us.json"
    },
  }
```

additonal packages:

- `"ts-jest": "^24.0.2",`
- `"jest": "^26.6.3","jest-junit": "^12.0.0",`
- `"@types/jest": "^26.0.15",`
- `"identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",`

On the other hand, rather than `enzyme`, I am using `react-testing-library`